# How can I get a data set that exists in my explorer get into my library in sas?

Tags: sas

I am relatively new to sas. I have a data set in one of my folders among the Explorer but I need to have it in my Library called WORK so that I can use it, the file ends with .sas7bdat
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need it in your `WORK` to work with it.

To use `MY_TABLE.sas7bdat` in `c:\my\path`, you just declare a library `libname MY_LIB 'c:\my\path';`, which you then use (more or less) as a tables-space or Db2 schema. For instance

- `data MY_DATA; set MY_LIB.MY_TABLE;`
- `select ... from MY_LIB.MY_TABLE where ...;`